# Problems putting a border on a HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to achieve this effect:

[image]

I have tried the following but it does not work at all (no borders appear at all). Can anyone explain how to achieve what I would like.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .withBorder {
    border: 1px;
  }

  .withoutBorder {
    border: 0px;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class = 'withoutBorder'> cell1 </td>
    <td class = 'withBorder'> cell2 </td>
    <td class = 'withoutBorder'> cell3 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = 'withBorder'> cell1 </td>
    <td class = 'withoutBorder'> cell2 </td>
    <td class = 'withBorder'> cell3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.withBorder {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You should have defined **type** and **color** after **size** of the border.

Comment: Perfect - just the ticket.

Answer (score 5):

You need `border-collapse` on the `table`, like so:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.withBorder {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.withoutBorder {
    border: none;
}
```

Attached a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogckL47f/).

Also, you can make your code more concise by using `nth-child` selectors. You don't need to explicitly set class names on each table cell. This solution works if you add rows or columns to your table too. See [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogckL47f/1/).

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n+2),
tr:nth-child(2n+2) td:nth-child(2n+1) {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```